# cp: how to follow symbolic links in DEST?

Tags: unix, cp

For example, I want c be copyed into ab/ not change a/b into a folder with c:

```
$ mkdir /a /b /ab /b/b
$ ln -s /ab /a/b
$ touch /b/b/c
$ ls -Rl
.:
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2  a
drwxrwxr-x 2  ab
drwxrwxr-x 3  b

./a:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1  b -> ab

./ab:
total 0

./b:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 b

./b/b:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 c
```

---

I tried:

```
cp -rf /b/* /a/

cp: cannot overwrite non-directory ‘a/b’ with directory ‘b/b
```

even with flag -dHlLP dosent work.

Answer (score 1):

For some security reason:

```
cp -rf b/* a/
```

Gives:

```
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `a/b' with directory `b/b'
```

So you can only do this to unlink the symlinc:

```
unlink a/b
```

Then

```
cp -rf b/* a/
```

In general, it's bad thing to manipulate too much directory structures, risk of erasing files is considerable, in you case you use root /, the risk is greater, to be avoided.